# OpenCV Template Matching Error

Tags: c++, opencv, qt4

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Global Variables
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;
char* image_window = "Source Image";
char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load image and template
  img = imread( "test.png", 1 );
  templ = imread( "template.png", 1 );

  /// Create windows
  namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  /// Create Trackbar
  char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
  createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

  MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}

/**
 * @function MatchingMethod
 * @brief Trackbar callback
 */
void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
  /// Source image to display
  Mat img_display;
  img.copyTo( img_display );

  /// Create the result matrix
  int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
  int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

  result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );

  /// Do the Matching and Normalize
  matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
  double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
  Point matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

  /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
  if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    { matchLoc = minLoc; }
  else
    { matchLoc = maxLoc; }

  /// Show me what you got
  rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
  rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

  imshow( image_window, img_display );
  imshow( result_window, result );

  return;
}
```

While using the example code from opencv I come across the following error. I am pretty new to QT C++ and I don't know how to debug this. Normally in Java I would use stacktrace and tell me where in the code I am screwing up but this seems to point directly to the library.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (corrsize.height <= img.rows +
>   templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1) in
>   crossCorr, file c:/OpenCV/opencv /modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp,
>   line 70 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what():  c:/OpenCV/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:70:
>   error: (-215)  corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 &&
>   corrsize.width <= img.cols + te mpl.cols - 1 in function crossCorr

**UPDATE**: The built .exe file runs but not when it's launched from QtCreator. I was able to launch the built .exe file. I copied over the files from the QtSDK/Simulator/mingw/bin and to my surprise the application ran successfully. When I click the Run button inside Qt Creator it will throw the same error message above.

Comment: You should still be able to use your debugger to find the last line of your code that is executed before the crash.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when I had given incorrect file names as image/templ. If you give incorrect file names, it wouldn't give an error, but the created Mat would be of size (0,0). Hence the assertion error.

When I gave the correct image, the program was working well.

My output (with correct image filenames)
[image]

P.S. I am using OpenCV 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from result Mat size, when you use create method of Mat first parameter is **number of rows** and second one is **number of col**, so you should change `result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );` to `result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );`

Comment: yes...I read the docs and while you are correct I still get the same error message.

Comment: okay the exe built will run but not from QtCreator...strange.

Comment: check that `imread` can find image files, when you run it from qtcreator. i think it's related to the working directory of program when run in qtcreator.

Comment: I put it in the same directory as what the console outputted. however, when I build the exe, it is able to find the image files. when I run from qt creator, it is unable to find the image files....

Comment: you can do one of these **1.** change working directory in qtcreator project settings, **2.** put the images in the same directory of exe file and use `qApp->applicationDirPath();` to get fullpath of image files instead of relative one. **3.** embed images in a resource file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I could only get it to work after forceably changing both types, like so:

```
cvtColor(src,src,CV_8UC1);  //channels need to match template
cvtColor(template,template,CV_8UC1);  //channels need to match template
```